# Does Jython have a 'startup file' like Python?

Tags: python, jython

Jython 2.7b2 does not respect `PYTHONSTARTUP`, nor does it respect `JYTHONSTARTUP`.  If there is no such thing in Jython, what would be a good workaround?

Comment: Ive never understood the need nor desire for these types of things...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Might be useful if someone is trying to use Python as a shell?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, it's desirable if you want to write code to inspect objects in the midst of an interactive Python session.  For example: https://github.com/darius/columnize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jython, you can `import user` to arrive at nearly the same result.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/user.html) indicate the differences between this approach and the `PYTHONSTARTUP` approach.